# How to test for attribute completeness on a resulting document using XSpec?

Tags: xslt, xspec

I'm creating a test that uses an input XML and want to test the presence of an element and the right attributes of the said element. Having difficulty getting this to work *right*, however.

This is what I've setup:

```
<x:scenario label="Scenarios for testing Choice handling">
    <x:context href="input.xml"></x:context>
    <x:scenario label="Choices with DataElements">
        <x:expect label="Abstract class in the uml:Model with an isAbstract attribute" test="/xmi:XMI/uml:Model/packagedElement/packagedElement[@name = 'AdditionalExposureDetail']">
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="..." name="AdditionalExposureDetail" visibility="public" isAbstract="true">...</packagedElement>
        </x:expect>
```

The idea is that the output transformation will contain an element at */xmi:XMI/uml:Model/packagedElement/packagedElement[@name = 'AdditionalExposureDetail']* (it does) and the element will have the right attribute signature. After many, many iterations however I cannot get it to work - the latest one gives an empty node-set as the result, even though running the transformation manually, the XPath is correct!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the XSLT that you have so far?

Comment: The XSLT transform or the XSpec? I don't think I can share the transform yet :(

Comment: I think the issue is that Saxon-EE is being used by oXygen and that seems to be causing some issues for my document (unfortunately the output is not visible). I've been running my transformation with -PE and -HE with good success until now. So I'll try and run XSpec with -HE and see what happens then - that could be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After much more prodding, it came down to XSPec running the transformation somehow quite wrong and the resulting document not looking right at all - hence testing against it was failing. I've reported the [issue here](https://code.google.com/p/xspec/issues/detail?id=60), we'll see what happens then...